# How to use ng-repeat with a JSON file stored in localStorage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I get objects stored in localstorage

**Here is my html :**

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="sign in monobjet_json.List">
  <ion-item>
  <div class="video-container">
    <img  ng-src="{{sign.src}}" width="200" height="150"/>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-icon-left assertive">
    <i class="icon ion-android-document"></i>
    {{sign.texte}}
  </div>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error\issue?,  and also don't use interpolation (`{{..}}`)in angular directive, so in `ng-src` remove them, do it like :  `ng-src="sign.src"`

Comment: // here is js
        
       
    
         app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $http.get('signs.json').then(function(res){
            $scope.signs = res.data; 
            var monobjet_json = JSON.stringify(res.data);
            localStorage.setItem("objet",monobjet_json);
            });
            var monobjet_json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objet"));

Comment: @NozhaGharnougui you can edit the question. Please put that in question itself

Answer (score 0):

Access the data from the local storage on the js code not form the html directly. 
First check if the data is already in the storage so you can access it directly without making a backend call, if it is not there then make a call to the backend, get the data and store it in local storage.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http){ 
     var item =  localStorage.getItem("object") 
     if(item) {
       $scope.monobjet_json = items;
     }
     else {
      $http.get('signs.json').then(function(res) { 
       $scope.signs = res.data; 
       $scope.monobjet_json = JSON.stringify(res.data); 
       localStorage.setItem("object", $scope.monobjet_json); 
     }); 
    }
```

Comment: and ng-repeat="sign in monobjet_json.List"
stay like that?

Comment: well yes if your object has the property List

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be to create an angular service which handles the json payload from source and returns a js object representation of the json data. This would potentially contain your array of values as a property.

Service:

```
return $http.get({'... your endpoint here'})
```

Controller:

```
var ctrl = this;
service.getJson()
  .then(function(res){
    ctrl.list = res.data
  }
```

Now in html you you just bind your ng-repeat to get your image src. Note: $ctrl indicates use of angular component else Replace $ctrl with your controller as var.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="sign in $ctrl.list">
<ion-item>
<div class="video-container">
<img  ng-src="{{sign.src}}" width="200" height="150"/>
</div>
<div class="item item-icon-left assertive">
<i class="icon ion-android-document"></i>
{{sign.text}}
</div>
</ion-item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http.get('signs.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.signs = res.data; 
    localStorage.remove('object');
  if(localStorage.getItem('object') == null){
  var monobjet_json = JSON.stringify(res.data.json());
  localStorage.setItem("object",monobjet_json);
 }
});

 if( localStorage.getItem('object') != null){
   var monobjet_json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("object"));
   var List = monobjet_json.List;// TODO: get some of data from json object
 }

});
```